# Making old stairs less creaky before carpeting without access to underside

Tags: stairs

I have a Victorian house with a creaky old staircase. Certain steps are worse than others. It looks like the risers have actually shrunk over the years.

We plan to have it carpeted in the next month. What can I do to the steps to reduce the creak, without having access to the underside, or taking the stair to bits?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you have access beneath?

Comment: They've been beautifully replastered and painted.

Comment: Leave it.  When you have teens you'll understand.

Answer (score 3):

The risers aren't typically supporting the treads.  If the treads are squeaking it is typically the wood tread moving due to a nail that is no longer holding it tight.  You want to use screws or ring shank nails that will not pull out.  You could also add PL400 but screws are probably enough.

Screws and a modern driver will get the treads tight to the stringers and prevent future movement.

Comment: Trim-head screws, it the systems sold specifically for fixing squeeks where the screw head breaks off and is removed to leave a smaller hole, might be worth considering, though the latter are more advantageous when trying to fix squeeks without taking up carpet.

Comment: I disagree with your first statement. Every stair set I've built has the treads resting on the risers with construction adhesive between. They absolutely do support the treads between stringers.

Comment: modern stairs have stringers and then you have plywood treads and risers and then you finish with your finish material.  The stringers are supporting the treads.  The riser can re-enforce the whole setup but the stringer is supporting the tread - exterior stairs often skip the riser entirely.

Answer (score 2):

**Glue and screws.**

New stair sets are built with lots of construction adhesive. Its purpose is to prevent micro-movement, which is the source of most squeaks and clicks. So, remove the cove molding under the tread nosings and inject as much heavy-duty construction adhesive in that gap as you can. Do the same at the bottoms of the risers. Wipe away any excess.

Then, add screws. 2-1/2" or 3" basic gold screws are great, but look for torx drive and self-drilling tips. If you can't find the latter, pre-drill. That wood is old and brittle. Also countersink in advance. Don't try to pull heads in mechanically or you'll split your treads. Position the screws at least 3/4" behind the face of the stringer, and angle them back slightly.

By tightening everything as well as you can and bonding it with adhesive you'll dramatically reduce noise. I'd even glue the cove molding, either with overflow of construction adhesive or with wood glue.

Answer (score 1):

Get a stack of shims and some waterproof wood glue from your home store. Apply some glue into the gaps and shims and slide the shims into the gap and tap in tight with a hammer. Use a utility knife or sharp chisel to cut off the excess shim.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously fill the gaps as much as you can. Probably use some wood shims to make it stronger and prevent movement.

Using appropriate nails, nail them at 15-30 angle to prevent the nails from coming out. This might take some practice to do since the normal is straight down. Use nail sinker tool to sink them below the surface.

To find out where to nail, use the existing nails as guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an offbeat suggestion:

It seems to me like one of the problems is that the treads are sagging.  You could bore a couple of access holes (big enough to stick your hands and tool through) in the risers with a hole saw (save the plugs):
[image]

and screw brackets into the back:
[image]
[image]

(your choice of which screw holes to use)

Then glue the plugs back in place, do a little filling and sanding, and paint over.  Even if you're carpeting right now, you might want to get rid of the carpet in the future, so make it as smooth as you can now.

Comment: @JacobKrall that's what the access holes are for...

Comment: Dunno how I missed that, sorry.

Comment: Cool idea. I've got brackets which I was going to fit on the front, as carpet is coming, but this is clever